# Are replacement bath fans available with the same mount and opening size?

Tags: bathroom, fans

Current bathroom fan sounds like a jet engine for about 30 seconds and then sounds normal.  Not sure how old it is but the house is from the 70s.  I'm hoping to be able to replace it with a new one that wouldn't require any work aside from plug and play.

I don't see any make/model markings and was hesitant to try and take it down.  Is this style still on the market?  I'd like something that fits the same hole/brackets so I'm not doing any additional drilling or mounting.

Photos: https://ibb.co/album/GHRBT8

Thank you

Comment: Please put your photos here in the question post.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd expect anyone to know this without model and size information. That said, it's unlikely that you'll find a plug and play fan for what may be a 50 year old device.

Answer (score 2):

Start out by unplugging the motor from the side of the can and then remove the two screws at each end of the bracket supporting the motor. You should then be able to lower the bracket, motor and fan blades. Now the fun begins. Try cleaning up the motor and fan blades and drop some oil on the bearings of the motor. See if it works better. If not, take it to your home store and look for a similar fan that has the assembly similar to yours and screw it into your existing can. If nothing matches, try replacing just your motor and remove the fan blades from your old motor and press them on to your new motor. If none of this works, then you're looking at replacing the entire fan and housing and that gets a little involved.

Comment: Much appreciated.  Hopefully a good cleaning will get it up and running again.